# Django Models - How to store fields in a dict

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I have a fairly simple user-model perfectly working.
In order to reduce code redundancy, I try to store fields inside a dictory for reasons you can easily guess.

Example:

```
def get_social_token(self,social_net=""):
   return self.social_dict[social_net]["token"]
```

If I don't do such a structure I must do some "if/then ... elif... else".
And of course I need to modify my code whenever I decide to add a new social network to my app.

I have tried two different approaches, both of them give me the same result:

- No error
- No field is actually detected and created in the DB

I'd like to mention that if I use a "conventional manner" to implement this behaviour such as:

- twitter_social_token = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)

It perfectly works, so it comes from the use of a dictionary.

Any idea to solve this ?
Btw. I would prefer avoiding using a new model and a foreign key... Only a One-to-One association, I would prefer not having to perform any "join" or select in another table...

Bellow, you'll find the two attempts I made which doesn't work (and I don't know why):

**First attempt:**

```
social_fields = {
    'twitter' : {
        'token'  : EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True),
        'secret' : EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    },
    'facebook' : {
        'token'  : EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True),
        'secret' : EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    },
    'gplus' : {
        'token'  : EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True),
        'secret' : EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    },
    'linkedin' : {
        'token'  : EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True),
        'secret' : EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    },
}
```

**Second attempt:**

```
social_tokens = dict()

social_tokens["twitter"] = dict()
social_tokens["facebook"] = dict()
social_tokens["linkedin"] = dict()
social_tokens["gplus"] = dict()

social_tokens["twitter"]["token"] = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
social_tokens["twitter"]["secret"] = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)

social_tokens["facebook"]["token"] = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
social_tokens["facebook"]["secret"] = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)

social_tokens["linkedin"]["token"] = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
social_tokens["linkedin"]["secret"] = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)

social_tokens["gplus"]["token"] = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
social_tokens["gplus"]["secret"] = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

Thanks for the help dear friends,

Jonathan

Comment: **Please** do not post screenshots of code; post the actual code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I fixed my message then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would definetely works, however as you seen I use Encrypted Fields in order to keep secure my user's tokens and secret_tokens.

I hope this not a bad thing to do or some kind of anti-pattern.
Feel free to share a better way doing this.

I just found a workaround which actually works exactely the way I wanted, even if it's not super efficiant from my point of view.

**Here is you access the data:**

```
from application.models import *
tmp_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username="random_username")

print (getattr(tmp_user, tmp_user.social_fields["twitter"]["token"]))
>>> e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a ### This token is a fake !
```

**Here is how managed to do this:**

```
twitter_token          = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
twitter_token_secret   = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)

facebook_token         = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
facebook_token_secret  = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)

gplus_token            = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
gplus_token_secret     = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)

linkedin_token         = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
linkedin_token_secret  = EncryptedCharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)

social_fields = {
    'twitter' : {
        'token'  : "twitter_token",
        'secret' : "twitter_token_secret"
    },
    'facebook' : {
        'token'  : "facebook_token",
        'secret' : "facebook_token_secret"
    },
    'gplus' : {
        'token'  : "gplus_token",
        'secret' : "gplus_token_secret"
    },
    'linkedin' : {
        'token'  : "linkedin_token",
        'secret' : "linkedin_token_secret"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, without using join you have 3 different way:

- [django-picklefield](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield)

> django-picklefield provides an implementation of a pickled object
>   field. Such fields can contain any picklable objects.

From their documentation, to use; just define a field in your model:

```
>>> from picklefield.fields import PickledObjectField
... class SomeObject(models.Model):
...     args = PickledObjectField()
```

and assign whatever you like (as long as it’s picklable) to the field:

```
>>> obj = SomeObject()
>>> obj.args = ['fancy', {'objects': 'inside'}]
>>> obj.save()
```

- [django-jsonfield](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield)

> django-jsonfield is a reusable Django field that allows you to store
>   validated JSON in your model.
>   It silently takes care of serialization. To use, simply add the field
>   to one of your models.

To use, just install the package, and then use the field:

```
from django.db import models
import jsonfield

class MyModel(models.Model):
    the_json = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

- [hstorefield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield) iff you're using PostgreSQL

> A field for storing mappings of strings to strings. The Python data
>   type used is a dict.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import HStoreField
from django.db import models

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = HStoreField()

Dog.objects.create(name='Rufus', data={'breed': 'labrador'})
```